# StringBuilder.AppendLine not working when convert to string

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

For example a `newPassword` value of "Abcdefg".
This will pass the first 2 criteria but fail the second 2 in the below code.

This is what is being outputted:

> Password should contain at least one numeric value (0 through 9).
>   Password should contain at least one non-alphabetic character (for
>   example: !, $, #, %).

Note: I'm using a label in an .aspx page to output this text.

```
    private string ValidatePasswordComplexity(string newPassword)
    {
        StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();

        var hasNumber = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");
        var hasUpperChar = new Regex(@"[A-Z]+");
        var hasLowerChar = new Regex(@"[a-z]+");
        var hasSymbols = new Regex(@"[!@#$%^&*()_+=\[{\]};:<>|./?,-]");
        var criteria = 0;

        if (hasUpperChar.IsMatch(newPassword))
            criteria++;
        else 
        {
            errorMessage.Append("Password should contain at least one English uppercase letter (A through Z).");
            errorMessage.AppendLine();
        }

        if (hasLowerChar.IsMatch(newPassword))
            criteria++;
        else
        {
            errorMessage.Append("Password should contain at least one English lowercase letter (a through z).");
            errorMessage.AppendLine();
        }

        if (hasNumber.IsMatch(newPassword))
            criteria++;
        else
        {
            errorMessage.Append("Password should contain at least one numeric value (0 through 9).");
            errorMessage.AppendLine();
        }

        if (hasSymbols.IsMatch(newPassword))
            criteria++;
        else
        {
            errorMessage.Append("Password should contain at least one non-alphabetic character (for example: !, $, #, %).");
        }

        if (criteria >= 3)
            return "Success";
        else
            return errorMessage.ToString();
    }
```

I want it to output:

> Password should contain at least one numeric value (0 through 9).
>
> Password should contain at least one non-alphabetic character (for
>   example: !, $, #, %).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `List<string>` to only store items and simply join them at the end: `return string.Join("\n\n", list)`.

Comment: How you check your output, from where? Some textbox, unittest, debug tools?

Comment: Are you sure that you get output you showed in question - where between two message no break line at all. (notice that in stackoverflow you need two spaces in the end of line if you want break lines works)

Comment: I saw the correct result when I tested it. One new line between first and second message.

Comment: Is it normal that in your first blockquote the two sentences are on the same line ? Or is it a formatting mistake ? To fix it you can add <br> at the end of the first line...

Comment: Is your final display is in HTML format?

Comment: I'm using a label in an .aspx page to output this text. I have updated the question.

Comment: Why don't you go on msdn and look for stringbuilder there, you seem to lack basic understanding of it and documentation will tell you a lot of new things it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MartinVerjans and @Ian for pointing me in the right direction. I have found a solution.

I changed this line..

```
errorMessage.AppendLine();
```

to this..

```
errorMessage.Append("<br />");
```

Comment: `errorMessage` is a `StringBuilder` you don't need to "loop" it after to replace new line with "br", just append `<br />` straight in `StringBuilder`. Instead of `errorMessage.AppendLine()` use `errorMessage.Append("<br />");`

Comment: @Fabio You are correct. I've updated my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `AppendLine` twice instead of once:

```
errorMessage.AppendLine("Password should contain at least one numeric value (0 through 9).");
errorMessage.AppendLine();
```

Otherwise, the first `Append` would not produce a new line.

Comment: That's incorrect, if I just use AppendLine everywhere instead of append I would not need 2 each time. It inserts a newline after the line you append with appendline... I mean test this solution and insert text in the 2nd appendline. They both start at a new line so...

Comment: in OP's code `.Append` always used together with `AppendLine` - so his error messages should be separated by break line(except last `else` condition)

Comment: @Ian It looks like he just wants the other line to start at a new line. (because current output is like `.Append()`) not a newline in between. But that could be my wrong interpretation. The output he specifies isnt even reproducible if you use appendline though.

Comment: @EpicKip I think it is wrong interpretation. Looks at the markdown formatting of the post. Both sentences are on a new line. What op wants is an empty line between the outputs...

Comment: If you click the `Edit` you could see that the desired output has one extra line than the original

Comment: @MartinVerjans That makes sense. Although it is a very stupid question in that case as he is already using appendline to make a newline. Prime example of "lacks basic understanding".

Comment: @Ian Got it now, my bad. Should'v checked there, can't expect post to be what they intended haha.

Comment: Or, it could be that @MartinVerjans is right, if the final display is in HTML format, he should add `<br/>`

Comment: @Ian No my misstake, <br> is also a way to create a new line in the post... I didn't know about the two spaces at the end of the line...

Answer (score 0):

Your code **does** in fact produce *exactly one* new line just as you coded it. If you want more than one, you need to use `AppendLine()` more than once:

[image]

Code used:

```
namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;

    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static string ValidatePasswordComplexity(string newPassword)
        {
            StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();

            var hasNumber = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");
            var hasUpperChar = new Regex(@"[A-Z]+");
            var hasLowerChar = new Regex(@"[a-z]+");
            var hasSymbols = new Regex(@"[!@#$%^&*()_+=\[{\]};:<>|./?,-]");
            var criteria = 0;

            if (hasUpperChar.IsMatch(newPassword))
                criteria++;
            else
            {
                errorMessage.Append("Password should contain at least one English uppercase letter (A through Z).");
                errorMessage.AppendLine();
            }

            if (hasLowerChar.IsMatch(newPassword))
                criteria++;
            else
            {
                errorMessage.Append("Password should contain at least one English lowercase letter (a through z).");
                errorMessage.AppendLine();
            }

            if (hasNumber.IsMatch(newPassword))
                criteria++;
            else
            {
                errorMessage.Append("Password should contain at least one numeric value (0 through 9).");
                errorMessage.AppendLine();
            }

            if (hasSymbols.IsMatch(newPassword))
                criteria++;
            else
            {
                errorMessage.Append("Password should contain at least one non-alphabetic character (for example: !, $, #, %).");
            }

            if (criteria >= 3)
                return "Success";
            else
                return errorMessage.ToString();
        }

        internal static void Main()
        {
            var text = ValidatePasswordComplexity("Abcdefg");

            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```